# I am using Schemacrawler Utility to compare two databases in java so I am trying to get triggers information but it is giving empty array

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, schema, schemacrawler

This is the code I am using to get triggers information using schemacrawler utility class in java. I am extracting metadata so i need whole metadata information.

`public class Metadata {

```
/**
 * Extracts metadata from a database connection using SchemaCrawler tool
 * 
 * @param SourceDetails , contains the connection details for database connection
 * @return a DbMetadata object containing metadata consisting of schema,table,column,and data types.
 */

public DbMetadata MetadataExtract(SourceDetails source) throws IOException {
System.out.println("Line 54.......");
    DbMetadata data = new DbMetadata();
    //StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    
    final SchemaCrawlerOptions options =
            SchemaCrawlerOptionsBuilder.newSchemaCrawlerOptions();
    
    final Catalog catalog = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(ConnectionUtil.getConnection(source), options);
    ArrayList<String> colNames = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tableNames =  new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> dataTypes =  new ArrayList<>();
    String schemaName = source.getName();
    
    String[] url =source.getUrl().split(Pattern.quote("/"));
    for(int i=0; i<url.length; i++) {
        //System.out.println("URL......writeMetaData...."+url[i]);
        }
    String[] URLx = url[0].split(Pattern.quote(":"));
    String DBName= URLx[1];
    System.out.println("DBname..."+DBName);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
    String fileName ="File"+timestamp.getDate()+timestamp.getMonth()+timestamp.getYear()+timestamp.getHours()+timestamp.getMinutes()+timestamp.getSeconds()+".xlsx";
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(fileName);
    Workbook workbook=null;
    Sheet sheet=null;
    Sheet sheet1=null;
    Sheet sheet2=null;
    int i=0,k=0,l;
    if(file.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("inside if condition line 79.....");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        
        //Creating workbook from input stream
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

        //Reading sheets of excel file
       sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
       sheet1 = workbook.getSheetAt(1); 
       sheet2 = workbook.getSheetAt(2);
        //Getting the count of existing records
       i = sheet.getLastRowNum();
       k = sheet1.getLastRowNum();
       //l = sheet2.getLastRowNum();
       l=2;
       inputStream.close();
      
    }
    else {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Column");
        sheet1= workbook.createSheet("Table");
        sheet2 =workbook.createSheet("Schema");
        Row header1=sheet.createRow(0);
        header1.createCell(0).setCellValue("ColumnName");
        header1.createCell(1).setCellValue("Datatype");
        header1.createCell(2).setCellValue("DefaultValues");
        header1.createCell(3).setCellValue("isPrimaryKey");
        header1.createCell(4).setCellValue("TableName");
        i=1;
        Row header2=sheet1.createRow(0);
        header2.createCell(0).setCellValue("TableName");
        header2.createCell(1).setCellValue("SchemaName");
        header2.createCell(2).setCellValue("DBName");
        k=1;
        Row header3=sheet2.createRow(0);
        header3.createCell(0).setCellValue("SchemaName");
        header3.createCell(1).setCellValue("DBName");
        l=1;
    }
    
    for (final Schema schema : catalog.getSchemas())
    {
        
          
        Map<String,ArrayList<String>> tableColumnNames=new LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
        if (schemaName.equals(schema.toString())){
    
            
                  
              for (Table table : catalog.getTables(schema))
              {
                 
                  
                  System.out.println("Triggers_______"+table.getTriggers());
                 
                    for(schemacrawler.schema.Trigger trigger : table.getTriggers()) {
                        String triggerName= trigger.getFullName();
                        System.out.println("Triggers...."+ triggerName);
                    }
                System.out.print("o--> " + table);
                tableNames.add(table.getName());
                String tableName=table.getName();
                //colNames.add("----------------------------");
                //dataTypes.add("----------------------------");
                ArrayList<String> columnNames=new ArrayList<String>();
                
                    for (Column column : table.getColumns())
                    {
                        
                        System.out.println("o--> " + column + " (" + column.getColumnDataType().getJavaSqlType()+ ")");
                        
                        colNames.add(column.getFullName().replace(schemaName + ".", "")+" = "+column.getDefaultValue()+"."+column.isPartOfPrimaryKey());
                        dataTypes.add(column.getFullName().replace(schemaName + ".", "") + " = " + column.getColumnDataType().toString().toLowerCase());
                        
                        columnNames.add(column.getFullName().replace(schemaName + ".", "").replace(tableName+".","" )+"."+column.getColumnDataType()+"."+column.getDefaultValue()+"."+column.isPartOfPrimaryKey());
                
                    }
                    
                        tableColumnNames.put(tableName, columnNames);
                        
                }
              
              
             System.out.println("Table Column Names...."+tableColumnNames);
             
             /** Column Sheet   */
             for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> map: tableColumnNames.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("106 line no key: " + map.getKey() + " value: " + map.getValue());
                 
                 
                 String key=map.getKey(); 
                 ArrayList<String> value=map.getValue();
                 

                 for(String str:value)
                 {
                     StringTokenizer stz=new StringTokenizer(str,".");
                     String o=stz.nextToken();
                     String t=stz.nextToken();
                     String st=stz.nextToken();
                     String pk=stz.nextToken();
                     int  j=0;
                     Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
                     Cell cell = row.createCell(j);
                        cell.setCellValue(o);
                        j++;
                        row.createCell(j).setCellValue(t);
                        j++;
                        row.createCell(j).setCellValue(st);
                        j++;
                        row.createCell(j).setCellValue(pk);
                        j++;
                        row.createCell(j).setCellValue(key);
                         i++;
                         
                         
                 }  
                    
    }
            
              /** Table Sheet   */           
             for (final Table table : catalog.getTables(schema))
              {
                 System.out.println("Line no 176....."+table.getName());
                    
                      int m=0; 
                      Row row1 = sheet1.createRow(k);
                      
                      Cell cell1 = row1.createCell(m); 
                      cell1.setCellValue(table.getName());
                      m++;
                      row1.createCell(m).setCellValue(schema.getFullName()); 
                      m++;
                      row1.createCell(m).setCellValue(DBName); 
                      k++;
                    
              }
              /** Schema Sheet  */
              System.out.println("Line no 232...."+schema.getFullName());
              int n=0;
              Row row2= sheet2.createRow(l);
              Cell cell2 = row2.createCell(n);
              cell2.setCellValue(schema.getFullName());
              n++;
              row2.createCell(n).setCellValue(DBName); 
             
              
             
                
              /** writing file  */
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                workbook.write(fos);
                workbook.close();
                
                data.setColNames(colNames);
                data.setSchemaName(schemaName);
                data.setTableNames(tableNames);
                data.setDataTypes(dataTypes);
                
                return data;
                
            }
            
        
    }
    return null;
    
}`
```

I am expecting triggers data from table in java code using schemacrawlerutility, I have already triggers created in my database

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use the maximum info-level. See [the example code](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/main/schemacrawler-examplecode/src/main/java/com/example/ApiExample.java#L34-L38) for how to do this.
2. Please [increase the logging level](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/main/schemacrawler-examplecode/src/main/java/com/example/ApiExample.java#LL27C26-L27C26) if you need to send logs as suggested on [the SchemaCrawler website](https://www.schemacrawler.com/consulting.html)
3. Please make sure that the SchemaCrawler plugin jars are on your CLASSPATH for the databases that you are working with.

Sualeh Fatehi
[SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/consulting.html)